# Input to exit java program when blank line entered

Tags: java, loops, java-7

I have written a RPN Calculator in Java, but I am struggling to get my code to exit when the user enters a blank line instead of an equation. The program needs to loop until this blank line is entered.

Below is my source code.

```
$`import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner; 
import java.io.*;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

public class Calculator {
private static Scanner input;
public static int invalidlines = 0;
public static int validlines = 0;
public static ArrayList<String> validList = new ArrayList<String>(); 

public void FileNotFoundException(){
System.out.println("Please enter a  valid expression!");

}

public static boolean isInt(String userinput) { 
    try {
        Integer.parseInt(userinput); // Try to parse. Makes sure that the values entered are actual numbers
        return true; // Boolean value to show if the equation entered is valid or not
    } 
    catch (NumberFormatException e) { 
        System.out.println("Please enter a  valid expression!");
        return false; 
    }
}
    public static boolean isValidLine(String line) {
        line = line.trim();
    if (line.length() <= 4) { // Trims the lines down to 4 and ensures there is no spaces being included
            return false; 
        } 
    else 
        {
        String[] calcarray = new String[3];
        calcarray = line.split(" ");
        String operators = new String("[+\\-\\*\\/]"); // Validator using regular expressions to check the operator used

    if (isInt(calcarray[0].toString()) && isInt(calcarray[1].toString()) && calcarray[2].matches(operators)) { // Checks that the operator in the string matches the ones in the regular expression 
        return true; 
}
    else 
{
        return false;
}
}
}
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
input = new Scanner(System.in);
String keyboardInput = new String();
String currentLine = new String();
Scanner kbScan = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Please press the letter F for file input or K for keyboard input");
        String inputString = new String(input.nextLine());
    int answer = 0;
    while (true){
    if (inputString.equals("K") || inputString.equals("k")) { 
        System.out.println("Please enter an equation");
        keyboardInput = kbScan.nextLine();
    }
    if (isValidLine(keyboardInput)) {
        String[] equation = new String[3];  // We know that this is only going to contain 3 to be valid
        equation = keyboardInput.split(" "); // split this up, as it's stored with the spaces.
    if (inputString.equals("") || inputString.equals(""));
    {
        System.exit(0);
    }
    int num1 = Integer.parseInt(equation[0]); 
    int num2 = Integer.parseInt(equation[1]);
    switch(equation[2]) { // This case switch checks the third position of the string to decide which operator is being used. It then works out the answer and breaks to the next instruction

    case("+"):
        answer = num1 + num2;
    break;
    case("-"):
        answer = num1 - num2; 
    break; 
    case("/"):
        answer = num1 / num2;
    break;
    case("*"):
        answer = num1 * num2;
    break;
}
        System.out.println("Your post fix expression: " + equation[0] + " " + equation[1] + " " + equation[2]);
        System.out.println("Your calculation: " + equation[0] + " " + equation[2] + " " + equation[1] + " = " + answer);
}
    else{ 
        System.out.println("The equation you entered is invalid");
 }
    if (inputString.equals("f") || inputString.equals("F")) { 
        try{
        //Open the file
            System.out.println("Enter File Name: ");
            FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream(input.nextLine()); // make a input stream
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fstream)); // pass input stream to a buffered reader for manipulation
            String strLine; // create string vars
        //loop to read the file line by line
        while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null)   { // Whilst the buffered readers read line method is not null, read and validate it.
            currentLine = strLine; 
        if(isValidLine(currentLine)) 
        { 
            validList.add(currentLine); 
            validlines++;
            String[] filearray = new String[3];
            filearray = currentLine.split(" ");             
        int val1 = Integer.parseInt(filearray[0]);
        int val2 = Integer.parseInt(filearray[1]);
            System.out.println("Your expression is: " + filearray[0] + " " + filearray[1] + " " + filearray[2]);
        switch(filearray[2]) { 
        case("+"):
                answer = val1 + val2;
            break;
        case("-"):
                answer = val1 - val2; 
            break; 
        case("/"):
                answer = val1 / val2;
            break;
        case("*"):
                answer = val1 * val2;
            break;
            }
            System.out.println("Your calculation is " + filearray[0] + " " + filearray[2] + " " + filearray[1] + " = " + answer);
            } 
        }
        }
            catch (FileNotFoundException e) 
            {
                System.out.println("Please Enter a valid file name");
            }
        }
}
}
}
```

Comment: Please format your code to use correct indentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use following code to check the variable in which you are taking the user input,whether it's empty or not?

I am assuming you are taking in a variable called **inputString**,then the code should be-

```
if(inputString.isEmpty())
{
    System.exit(0);
}
```

Comment: I have tried placing this within my code and it just carries on looping round and does not exit?

Comment: Try inputString.trim().isEmpty() instead

Comment: Still the same im afraid. I have placed the if statement after the one where it asks the user to input an equation  (Line 54) is this the correct place?

Comment: keyboardInput = kbScan.nextLine();
        if(keyboardInput.trim().isEmpty()){
            System.exit(0);
        }
Paste this code after line no 36 ie the one where you are taking input in variable.Noww it will surely work!

Comment: What happened was I didn't read your code and just assumed that you were using 'inputString' as input variable,and as it happens you were already using inputString for storing input type(K ot F) ,That's where confusion happened.

Comment: This stops the loop after nothing is entered which is whats needed but it needs to carry on looping until this point, as this now doesnt give the user an option in input another equation

Comment: Sorry, its working now, however it stops the file input part working?

Comment: If you don't want the code to stop once blank line is inserted,use continue; instead of System.exit(0)

Comment: I want the code to stop after the blank line is inputted which is what it does perfectly, however if I choose option F instead of K for the file input the code does not read this whereas is does when that snippet of code isnt inserted

Comment: For the file part to work properly you need to move that code snippet out of the if condition(the one where you are checking if inputString to be 'K')

Answer (score 0):

maybe you should use `break` instead of `System.exit(0)`.

Also, I would check for empty input as soon as I read the input.